# Rendering a deformation of a region of points on a vector field

Tags: differential-equations

I want to study how an area of points is deformed as it flows past a cylinder. I let the initial formation of the particle pack be a regular decagon (a polygon) centered at (−4,1)  and radius 0.5. In Mathematica, I  obtain a suitable starting polygon with the CirclePoints command by setting

```
pts0 = {-4,1}+0.5*# & /@ CirclePoints[20]
```

Now I solve the system of differential equations for twenty starting positions by the following:

```
    Clear [x0, y0, X, eqn, x, y, pl1, F, r]
F[x_, y_] := { 1 - (x ^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^2,-2x*y/(x^2+y ^2)^2}; 
F[{x_, y_}] := F[x, y]
r[t_] := {x[t], y[t]}
```

I then plot the vector field

```
pl1 = StreamPlot [F[x, y], {x, - 1, 2}, {y, 1, 3.5 }, StreamStyle -> Green ]
```

and then declare the points for solving the deformation at:

```
pts0 = {-4,1}+0.5*# & /@ CirclePoints[20]
```

Then using NDSolve I try to solve the ODE at these points:

```
sol = First [NDSolve [ r'[t] == F[r[t]] && r[0] == # , r[t], {t, - 0, 2.1 }]] &
solutions [t_] := r[t] /. sol /@ pts0 // Evaluate
```

I then get:

*The cell contents are too large for direct browser rendering. (this may slow down your browser)*

so I cannot get to the step where I assign polygons at the points to show deformation:

```
polygon [t_] :=
{
Opacity [0.05 ],
EdgeForm [Dashed ],
Polygon [solutions [t]]
};


Show [
Graphics [
polygon [t] /. {{t -> 0.0 }, {t -> 0.05 }, {t -> 0.1 }, {t -> 0.15 }, {t -> 0.2 }, {t -> 0.25 }}]
]
```

and I get this  graphics:

[image]

Then I try to extract various time-frames:

```
 times = Range [0.0, 0.3, 0.05 ]
    
  Show [
pl1,
Graphics [polygon [#] & /@ times , AspectRatio -> 1],
ParametricPlot [ solutions [t], {t, 0, 0.4 }, PlotStyle -> Red ]
]
```

and animate:

```
Animate [
Show [pl1, Graphics [polygon [t]]], {t, 0.0, 1.7 }
]
```

But  the polygons are shown on the plot but not when the collide with the cylinder:

[image]

and therefore the animation is stopping too soon, not showing the deformation of the region on the cylinder.

Any hints on what is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't reproduce the last screenshot. 2. As to the current code, the `StreamPlot` is at the domain `{x, -1, 2}, {y, 1, 3.5}` but you place the polygon around `{-4,1}`. Adding a `PlotRange -> All` option to `Show` will help you noticing what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean velocity in the x direction is about 1. The region what do you try to animate, has length in the x direction about 7. Therefore, the time to pass cylinder is about 7, while you use 1.7 only. So, the code is given by

```
F0[x_, y_] := {1 - (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2, -2 x*y/(x^2 + y^2)^2};
F[{x_, y_}] := F0[x, y];
r[t_] := {x[t], y[t]};
pl1 = StreamPlot[F0[x, y], {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> False, StreamStyle -> Blue];
pts0 = {-4, 1} + 0.5*# & /@ CirclePoints[20]; sol = 
 First[NDSolve[r'[t] == F[r[t]] && r[0] == #, r[t], {t, 0, 7}]] &;
solutions[t_] := r[t] /. sol /@ pts0 // Evaluate

polygon[t1_] := {Green, Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Dashed], 
   Polygon[solutions[t1]]};
lst = Table[Graphics[polygon[t1]], {t1, 0.25, 7, .25}];frames = Table[Show[pl1, lst[[i]]], {i, Length[lst]}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks Alexander! The animation looks great now!

Comment: I tried to insert a yellow circle at 0,0 of radius 1. But it does not enter in the image without problems. Should I insert it at "Table[Graphics" or "Table[Show[" part?

Comment: @Vangsnes Use `frames = 
 Table[Show[pl1, lst[[i]], Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}]], {i, 
   Length[lst]}]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev This animation looks great :)

Comment: Thanks Alexander!

Comment: @Vangsnes You are welcome!